# how to create a SmsMessage from a pdu object expecially when working wity WorkManager InputData considerring the pdu has been created as a String

Tags: android, android-workmanager, pdu

I am using a Broadcast Receiver to intercept incoming messages. I have passed the intent data from the OnReceive method to a WorkManager class. I want to get a SmsMessage from the pdu but since the data being received on the doWork method is String even the pdu object is a string therefore this becomes hard to create an SmsMessage object from such PDU. Below is my code for the Broadcast receiver;

````
      if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           final Bundle data = intent.getExtras();



            if (data != null){
                Data.Builder dataBuilder = new Data.Builder();
                for ( String key : data.keySet()){
                    dataBuilder.putString(key,String.valueOf(data.get(key)));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive:  key:" +key+ " and keyValue "+data.get(key));
                }
                WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
                OneTimeWorkRequest mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                        .Builder(MessageSyncWorker.class)
                        .setInputData(dataBuilder.build())
                        .build();
                mWorkManager.enqueue(mRequest);

                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Data: " +data);

            }

```


This is what am doing 
on the WorkManager class

```
public class MessageSyncWorker extends Worker {

    String sender, timestamp, msgID, text_message;
    private static final String TAG = "MessageSyncWorker";
    private static int counter = 0;
    public MessageSyncWorker(@NonNull Context context,
                             @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Data inputData = getInputData();
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork: " +" inputdata "+inputData +
                " DataValueMAP "+inputData.getKeyValueMap());

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        for (String key : inputData.getKeyValueMap().keySet()) {
//      extras.putString(key,String.valueOf(inputData.getString(key))); //This also works well
            extras.putString(key,inputData.getString(key));
            Log.d(TAG, "doWork: ExtrasKeySet " +extras.keySet());
            Log.d(TAG, "doWork: Extra Extra: "+inputData.getString(key));

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork:  Extras: Tena "+extras);

        processBundleData(extras);

        return Result.success();
    }

    private void processBundleData (Bundle bundle){
        if (bundle !=null){
            Object[] newpdusObj = new Object[] {  bundle.get("pdus") };
            Log.d(TAG, "processBundleData: Bundle "+newpdusObj);
            if (newpdusObj !=null){
                for (int i = 0; i < newpdusObj.length; i++){
                    SmsMessage currentMessage =
                            SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) newpdusObj[i]);
                    Log.d(TAG, "processBundleData: CurrentSMS "+currentMessage);

                }
            }

        }

    }

```

Below is my logs showing the Exception,
```
2019-10-21 19:53:34.597 2364-2532/com.techweezy.smartsync D/MessageSyncWorker: processBundleData: Bundle [Ljava.lang.Object;@38e5886
2019-10-21 19:53:34.837 2364-2415/com.techweezy.smartsync E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=66ed12df-eb08-4714-9360-932ad2280873, tags={ com.techweezy.smartsync.utils.MessageSyncWorker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:290)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
        at com.techweezy.smartsync.utils.MessageSyncWorker$override.processBundleData(MessageSyncWorker.java:74)
        at com.techweezy.smartsync.utils.MessageSyncWorker$override.doWork(MessageSyncWorker.java:63)
        at com.techweezy.smartsync.utils.MessageSyncWorker$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:119)
        at com.techweezy.smartsync.utils.MessageSyncWorker.doWork(Unknown Source:12)
````